# Is there a way to find and replace using mulitple sheets in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to replace a formula for an entire column. I am replacing previous months with the current month. I have created a list of months JAN, FEB, MAR, etc on a separate sheet. Is there an easy was to select an entire column and replacing text with the table created on the separate sheet?

Ex: JUN18 needs to be replaced with Aug18.

In addition, one column will need to date back 4 months. Jul18 replace with Aug 18, Jun 18 replace with Jul 18, May 18 replace with Jun 18, Apr 18 replace with May 18.

Any help would be appreciated!

Derek

***Edited from Answer below***

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim rng As range
Dim strsearch As String

strsearch = FormMonth

Set rng = Worksheets("Scripting Data").range("A:A").find(strsearch, xlValues, xlWhole)
```

This appears to be running properly, however I am struggling to discover a way to "find" this text on the second spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? As long as there are rules for what replaces what, should be fine.

Comment: you need vba, or you can do it using formulas?

Comment: I believe my script is selecting the correct text that I want to replace. I am struggling to find and replace this text in the second spreadsheet. I have posted the formula that I have thus far for selecting my current month from my reference list. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a loop through your sheets?